# C# UDP Multicast with multiple clients - only receiving message from one client

Tags: c#, networking, udp, broadcast, multicast

So I have created a simple UDP server that broadcasts a datagram to clients via multicast. Upon receiving this message, each client responds by sending a multicast datagram reporting some internal state.

Only the server is interested in the message sent by the clients, although the clients and servers all use the same UDP send/receive code.

My issue is that with multiple clients I only ever seem to receive a datagram from one client. The other client's messages are never received even though they are sent.

I am using Microsoft's UdpClient and listening for messages on a separate thread using UdpClient.Receive(IPEndpoint endpoint).

My UdpClient is initialised as follows:

```
_ipEndpoint = new IPEndpoint(ipAddress, port);
_udpClient = new UdpClient(port, ipAddress.AddressFamily) { MulticastLoopback = false, DontFragment = true };
_udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(ipAddress);
```

Listening is as follows, called within a while loop on a separate thread:

```
public bool ReceiveMessage(out BaseMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] dataBuffer = _udpClient.Receive(ref _ipEndpoint); 
        message = UdpSerializer.ByteArrayToObject(dataBuffer);
    }
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they all on the same subnet? Any firewall in place? Also might be helpful to do a network trace with wireshark.

Comment: They are all on the same subnet and all have the correct firewall permissions. If I close one client I get the other client's messages and vice versa. So its not a communication issue per se. Someone suggest it may be related to both messages being received at the same time by the server, but I thought in this scenario the other message would be stored in a buffer.

Comment: UPDATE: My initial assumption is incorrect. After some more debugging it appears that the server is sending out the multicast message, but only one of the clients is actually receiving it.